# Loading NSDictionary from Plist as Listed

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

I'm using `plist` to store **key-value** lists. When the application needs that list, trying load list to a **NSDictionary**. Everything is well until here.

Here how I load the plist file:

```
NSString *myPlistFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"cities" ofType: @"plist"];
cities = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: myPlistFilePath];
```

When we look at, `cities` is a `NSDictionary`. Then I pushed all list key values to a TableView, somehow its not listed as in plist file. Sorting random.

Is there way to figure out? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An  [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is not an ordered collection, that is, it does not guarantee to preserve order of the contents in any way. Its only function is to map from keys to values.

If you need the contents ordered, you can extract it from the NSDictionary using for example [keysSortedByValueUsingSelector](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:), which will extract the data in the collection, sort it by your criteria and store it in an (order preserving) NSArray.

Alternatively, consider using an Array in the root of the plist, containing an ordered list of city dictionaries.  Then if you iterate over the array contained therein, they will be in the array order contained in the plist.

Comment: Thanks for seminal answer.

Answer (score 1):

NSDictionary is not an ordered data structure.

Objects are listed based on `allKeys` functions and keys are listed in undefined way.

See the apple doc for `allKeys` function.

> > **allKeys** Returns a new array containing the dictionary’s keys.
> >
> > - (NSArray *)allKeys
>
> **Return Value** A new array containing the dictionary’s keys, or an empty
>   array if the dictionary has no entries.
>
> > **Discussion** The order of the elements in the array is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for answer, so what's your suggestion to load as listed?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to avoid using a selector to sort the keys, consider using an Array in the root of the plist.  Then when you iterate over the array, the order is preserved.  This runs o(n), which is shorter than the fastest possible sort algorithm by a factor of log(n)
eg:

```
cities{
  list[
    city{}
    city{}
    city{}
    ...
  ]
}
```